# Permission denied to create temporary file in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, codeblocks

When I try to 'Run Build Task' in VS Code using C/C++ plugin, I get the following error:

Assembler messages:

```
Fatal error: can't create C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp\cc2Ad432.o: Permission denied

The terminal process "C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -Command & 'C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\x86_64-8.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v6-rev0\mingw64\bin\g++.exe' -g c:\Users\UserName\projects\helloworld\helloworld.cpp -o c:\Users\UserName\projects\helloworld\helloworld.exe" terminated with exit code: 1.
Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

When I try to build a code in 'Code::Blocks' it displays the same error - `Can't create temporary file. Permission Denied`
I tried changing the value of TEMP and TMP user variables in 'Environment variables'. That solved the problem for me but it doesn't allow 'Windows Word' to create temporary files.

Comment: Your OS permissions are messed up somehow. This has nothing to do with C++, ask some Windows experts.

Comment: Check the permissions on your temp folder by right clicking it in explorer and going to properties

Comment: Just to check the obvious - that the original message did not say  `UserName` in the path?

Comment: i am having a similar problem when running a Go file.